# When initialising an object in java, how can I name the object based on a variable passed to the method?

Tags: java, class, dynamic, initialization, naming

I have a method where I pass a variable (in this case an integer but could just as easily be a String) and want to use the variable as the object name when initialising. For example:

```
public static void printPlayerSetup(int playerPosition, String name) {
  Player playerPosition = new HumanPlayer(name);
}
```

So for example, if playerPosition was "1" the new object created would be "1". Player is an abstract class and HumanPlayer is an extends this just to be clear.

Comment: Pass it into the player via a constructor parameter or a setter method.

Comment: Note: Variable "names" aren't really all that important, don't exist for many objects, and *almost* don't exist in compiled code. If an object is referred to by several variables, which one represents the "name" for this object? Much more important are *object **references*** and how they can be obtained.

Comment: ... If you must associate an object with an int, a clean way to do this is by using a Map such as a `HashMap<Integer, MyType>` or `ArrayList<MyType>` depending on need, but again don't put too much reliance on variable names since non-final variables can change references at the drop of a hat, and objects can be referred to by more than one variable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you for your help. I guess what I am trying to avoid is having to manually assign object names for each player "player1" "player2" etc. I will need to be able to refer to each object later on to access mutators or accessors ie player1.getName(); I wanted to generate the object name so that if the user inputs that there are going to be four players, 4 new objects will be created: player1, player2, player3, player 4.

Comment: Again,  there is no such thing as "object name", and I think that you are confusing variables with objects. Please read or re-read the duplicate